# how to add rel attribute to tr of table

Tags: php, html, rel

I need to add `rel` attribute to the row of this table for some reason.
I did this but it doesnt work. How should I do it?

```
<?php
    $query = $con->prepare("query");
    $query->execute();

    while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $res['name'];
        echo "<tr[rel = '".$id."']>";  
        echo "<td>".$res['roll']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['dept']."</td>";
    }     
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to prevent same table row from cloning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766505/how-to-prevent-same-table-row-from-cloning) (Maybe not duplicate, but clearly related to that previous question.)

Comment: is rel a legit attribute? Also you  forgot to close your `tr` tag in your script

Comment: I assume you know that `rel` is not allowed on `tr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `echo '<tr rel="'.$id.'">';`

`echo` outputs HTML code; `<tr[rel=whatever]>` is incorrect HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $res['name'];
    echo "<tr rel = '".$id."'>";  
    echo "<td>".$res['roll']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['dept']."</td>";
```