# On jquery is programmatically correct get an attribute after removed the element

Tags: jquery, variables, store, pseudo-element, attr

This question is to know if there are cross-browser compatibility, and if it is really sure always get the attribute value even after it was removed, for example, in these two cases:

```
var rel = $(this).closest("tr").remove().attr("rel");
```

or

```
var $deltr = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
// code using $deltr to store it
var rel = $deltr.attr("rel");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not certain what Question is ? Are you storing attribute of element as variable after that element is removed from document ? Is expected result not returned ?

Comment: What is the difference between these two approaches otherwise than using multiple lines in second approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, you cannot get the attr after the element has been removed.

Once `remove()`d, the element no longer exists in the DOM and cannot be restored (even if assigned to a variable), and is not available to probe its attributes.

In jQuery 1.4 the [`detach()` method](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) was created to remove an element from the DOM, but still keep it available for restore. But not `remove()`.

[This jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L69sm9x0/) allows you to experiment with getting the rel attribute before and after removing the element.

Note that `rel=` is an attribute of the anchor `<a>` tag, [not of a table tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767093/how-to-add-rel-attribute-to-tr-of-table), but I assume you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I maybe mistaken.

From what I understand you're asking what's the difference between this approach...

```
var rel = $(this).closest("tr").remove().attr("rel");
```

vs this approach?

```
var $deltr = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
// code using $deltr to store it
var rel = $deltr.attr("rel");
```

The difference between the two depends on who's coding. The point of the variables is a lot of times it's easier to store a larger string, method function, etc: instead of calling it multiple times.

In addition you may watch to look into [ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion)](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) (If you don't want to read you can [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsfbh17Ax9I) instead)

The only difference between the two depends on how a user is coding the application as everyone has their own style. In this case `$deltr` would be used throughout the application along with `rel`, they may not always be used together though

```
var $deltr = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
// code using $deltr to store it
var rel = $deltr.attr("rel");
```